# Advanced warnings and browser cipher testing

Tags: encryption, https, compatibility

We have a number of internet-facing web apps. When Chrome and Firefox dropped SSLv3 support a while ago due to Poodle, when Firefox started blocking any sites that had a Diffie-Hellman cipher enabled, and (most recently) when Chrome and Firefox dropped RC4 ciphers, we were unexpectedly hit with production issues. In each case, we only found out about the issues when our end-users started calling.

For the sake of this question, we're only concerned with the connection to the web server. Testing site layout and javascript is outside the scope.

I have written a few probes with PHP and nmap/OpenSSL, ie. to scan for SSLv3 and SHA1 certs. But I can't help but wonder if there's a cleaner and easier way to do this...especially to keep on top of it before we start receiving support calls about it.

A few questions:

1. Are there any mailing lists that might notify us in advance of browser changes that could "break" connections to our apps?

Due to resource constraints, hopefully such mailing lists would not be cluttered with "noise".

2. Is there a tool that we can leverage that will tell us if our app no longer works in a specific browser, without us having to tell it the conditions to test for?

For example, if Firefox disables SHA1 cert support tomorrow, we shouldn't need to tell this tool about it. Instead, it should just test with the default browser settings of the latest version.

Even if we have to tell the tool what changed, we can probably manage that... But hopefully we won't need to spend hours to add each test case.

Preferably, such a tool would run on-premises so we can test non-production environments and internal web appa. "Bonus points" if it can be fully automated and send an email when it finds an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions involving the recommendation of software tools or other resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow. This is because there is no universally accepted answer when these kinds of questions are asked, which can ultimately attract spam and dissension. Please read the following page on what kinds of questions you can ask: [help/on-topic]. That being said, if you have a specific programming question regarding cipher suite checking, then by all means please ask. Otherwise, this question will inevitably be closed. If you can describe clearly what the tool should do, then try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably going against the SO rules here but personally I find [SSL Labs testing tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) very good and it's kind of become an industry standard for testing your https config.

Plug in your website URL, hit go and a few minutes later you get a report and a grade and also tests against a wealth of common browsers. If you've any warnings or less than an A grade then you'll run into trouble sooner or later. With an A grade you should be fine to test it once a quarter as it's unlikely any issue will be so new and so severe that browser makers ban them so quickly.

There are other tools and that tool only works for public facing websites ([testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh) is a command line tool which does a similar job for internal sites but without the grading). But SSL Labs is free, simple to use, is kept up to date, and allows you to just concentrate on the issues it flags. Keeping up to date on all security issues and bugs can be very time consuming otherwise - especially for a small company.

There's also an api for it which I guess can be used for auto testing but not played with that as not found the need.

The Feisty Duck security newsletter is a monthly newsletter letting you know about changes in this space: https://www.feistyduck.com/bulletproof-tls-newsletter/. It cuts most of the noise out and is well worth subscribing to. Feisty Duck was set up by the creator of SSLLabs and the newsletter is run by a HTTPS uber geek (no offence intended!) who is aware of all incoming changes. And Vincent Lynch blogs about changes in an easily understandable way at at: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/

Other useful links worth checking occasionally for issues that might affect your site:

- [Google's security blog](https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/?m=1)
- [Google's webmaster blog](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/?m=1)
- [Firefox security blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/)

There's plenty of other security mailing lists and forums but they really will take up a lot of your time. Personally I find it interesting but realise most people are probably not the same! :-)

Comment: I'm really sorry for such a long delay in following up with this; I wasn't getting my SO notifications. Those blogs definitely look helpful! And you're right; mailing lists will probably consume all my time.

We recently stumbled into Chrome's latest change: Rejecting certs without SAN extensions. Luckily we found a registry workaround, so our internal apps would continue to function while we updated our CA. Still... Would've been nice to know about it before it happened, even if it was based on a change in standards many years ago. :)

Comment: I understand your pain. I love this stuff and regularly email round the company about issues like this but realise not everyone has a geek like me. I can only reiterate that SSLLabs's tool is the best resource for this and getting your settings up to spec (an 'A' grade) a quarterly check will prevent most issues. That's tougher for internal sites but keeping internal sites to same standards as external ones will help.

Comment: Some further things to keep you aware of your potential next problems: 1) http is increasingly getting flagged as insecure. At the moment for login details but soon for any inputs (https://security.googleblog.com/2017/04/next-steps-toward-more-connection.html?m=1) and 2) TLSv1.0 is in its way out and 3) perfect forward secrecy ciphers are the way forward so you should use these before the others are depreciated (basically use ECDHE ciphers).

Comment: Added two good resources to my answer to explain: 1) The TLS Newsletter and 2) The SSL Store blog.